# IB_DESIGNABLE for Objective C components being draw when editing associated xib file

Tags: ios, interface-builder, xib

I have a UIControl that loads it's UI from a xib file. I've updated it to be IB_DESIGNABLE. One of the things I've added in the ability to loads it's UI when the component is used in another xib or storyboard.

```
#if TARGET_INTERFACE_BUILDER
-(instancetype) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [self loadFromXib];
    return self;
}
#endif

-(id) awakeAfterUsingCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if ([self.subviews count] == 0) {
        return [self loadFromXib];
    }
    return self;
}

-(id) loadFromXib {
    UIControl *realControl = nil;
    Class thisClass = [self class];
    for (id obj in [[NSBundle bundleForClass:thisClass] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass(thisClass)
                                                               owner:nil // This must be nil or we get into a loop.
                                                             options:nil]) {
        if ([obj isKindOfClass:thisClass]) {
            realControl = obj;
            break;
        }
    }
    NSAssert(realControl != nil, @"Failed to find an object of type %@ in the xib file.", NSStringFromClass(thisClass));
    // copy control frame and settings here ....
    return realControl;
}
```

This works well, loading the UI when viewing the storyboard and running the app.

However when I go to edit the xib for the control itself, IB activates this code and draws the control under itself in IB. Thus I see it twice like this:

[image]

In this case you can see the label to the right which is the UILabel subview of the control, and the word 'Label' drawn underneath the UIImage which is where it would be if there was no image. This is where the IB preview is loading and drawing the control.

From what i've been able to figure out so far there are two options with getting previews to occur. Firstly when running the app, and secondly when the control is being displayed in IB.

Here I'm looking for a third option which is the ability to say, draw in IB, but not when editing the control itself, only when rendering the control when it's being used.

Has anyone figured out how to do this?

Comment: have you find a solution for that?

Comment: Not so far. Got a clue from someone last week that I have to investigate though. Will post again if I find anything out.